# Immutable type updater using a special constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods, immutability

I wanted to update some properties of my [UriString](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209777/replacing-uri-with-a-more-convenient-class) but since this type is immutable, it wouldn't work. Actually, I just wanted to update the `Path` property but I don't want to have a constructor  with several parameters like in the [other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193804/selective-updates-to-immutable-types) because this is too much work and sometime not desireable. Instead, I require the immutable type to have an *immutable-update-construtor* that takes the `ImmutableUpdate` object that I use for this purpose.

To the user it looks like a dummy class without any useful properties:

```
public sealed class ImmutableUpdate : IEnumerable<(PropertyInfo Property, object Value)>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<(PropertyInfo Property, object Value)> _updates;

    internal ImmutableUpdate(IEnumerable<(PropertyInfo Property, object Value)> updates)
    {
        _updates = updates;
    }

    public IEnumerator<(PropertyInfo Property, object Value)> GetEnumerator() => _updates.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _updates.GetEnumerator();
}
```

and it should, because it's only a carrier type for updates and an *alias* for the lengthy enumeration signature. These updates are created and used by the `ImmutableUpdater` that binds values to properties via their backing-fields and allows the `Bind` method to be called only from within the constructor of the object being updated. This should be a simple protection against mutating random instances. `ImmutableUpdate` has also an `internal` constructor and is `sealed` which also prevents using it in a wrong way. (`ImmutableUpdater` currently looks for properties that have no *setter* but extending it to understand some special attributes to customize this procees should be possible.)

```
public static class ImmutableUpdater
{
    public static T With<T, TMember>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TMember>> memberSelector, TMember newValue)
    {
        if (!(memberSelector.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"You must select a member. Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
        }

        if (!(memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo selectedProperty))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"You must select a property. Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
        }

        if (selectedProperty.GetSetMethod() != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"You must select a readonly property. Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
        }

        if (GetBackingField<T>(selectedProperty.Name) == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"You must select a pure readonly property (not a computed one). Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
        }

        var immmutableUpdateCtor =
            typeof(T)
                .GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(ImmutableUpdate) });

        var updates =
            from property in obj.ImmutableProperties()
            let getsUpdated = property.Name == selectedProperty.Name
            select
            (
                property,
                getsUpdated ? newValue : property.GetValue(obj)
            );

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new ImmutableUpdate(updates));
    }

    public static void Bind<T>(this ImmutableUpdate update, T obj)
    {
        // todo - this could be cached
        var isCalledByImmutableUpdateCtor = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod() == ImmutableUpdateConstructor(typeof(T));
        if (!isCalledByImmutableUpdateCtor)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"You can call '{nameof(Bind)}' only from within an ImmutableUpdate constructor.");
        }

        foreach (var (property, value) in update)
        {
            GetBackingField<T>(property.Name)?.SetValue(obj, value);
        }
    }

    private static FieldInfo GetBackingField<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var backingFieldBindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var backingFieldName = $"<{propertyName}>k__BackingField";
        return typeof(T).GetField(backingFieldName, backingFieldBindingFlags);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ImmutableProperties<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return
            typeof(T)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(p => p.GetSetMethod() is null);
    }

    private static ConstructorInfo ImmutableUpdateConstructor(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(ImmutableUpdate) });
    }
}
```

#### Example

Its usage is pretty simple, just use `With` to set a new value.

```
var user = new User();

var updatedUser = user
    .With(x => x.FirstName, "John")
    .With(x => x.LastName, "Doe")
    //.With(x => x.FullName, "Doe") // Boom!
    .Dump();

user.Dump();
```

This is the type using `Bind` inside its special constructor:

```
class User
{
    public User() { }

    public User(ImmutableUpdate update)
    {
        update.Bind(this);
    }

    public string FirstName { get; }

    public string LastName { get; }
}
```

---

Is this solution any better than others, or worse? What do you say? I'm not really concerned about performance as this won't be used for any crazy scenarios (yet).

Comment: I was literally just contemplating writing one of these... I was wondering how best to specify properties, and had completely forgotten about Expressions, so thanks ;)

Comment: At first blush, the chained `With`s that return a new object each time seem a little wasteful if the next one is discarding the previous. Perhaps it could return an "interim" container object that can accumulate the `With` expressions and a final `Apply()` that executes them once and produces a single `User` (in this case) object?

Comment: _You must select a pure readonly property_ that is just cruel xD

Comment: @dfhwze hahaha I probably should name this thing an immutable virus as it infects immutables from inside and eats them like a parasite ;-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of small things here. My bigger thought is in the comment on the original question.

**One:**

Empty collections are nice if `null`s show their ugly faces:

```
internal ImmutableUpdate(IEnumerable<(PropertyInfo Property, object Value)> updates)
{
    _updates = updates ?? Enumerable.Empty<(PropertyInfo Property, object Value)>();
}
```

**Two:**

```
    var immmutableUpdateCtor =
        typeof(T)
            .GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(ImmutableUpdate) });
```

is never used. I'd rewrite that little block as:

```
var immmutableUpdateCtor = ImmutableUpdateConstructor(typeof(T));

if (immutableUpdateCtor == null)
{
    return obj;
}

var updates =
    from property in obj.ImmutableProperties()
    let getsUpdated = property.Name == selectedProperty.Name
    select
    (
        property,
        getsUpdated ? newValue : property.GetValue(obj)
    );

return (T)immutableUpdateCtor.Invoke(new object[] { new ImmutableUpdate(updates) });
```

I'll addend more if I think of anything.

**Three:**

The caching of constructor information as was commented in the code:

```
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConstructorInfo> _ImmutableConstructors =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConstructorInfo>();

    private static ConstructorInfo ImmutableUpdateConstructor(Type type)
    {
        if (!_ImmutableConstructors.TryGetValue(type, out var constructor))
        {
            constructor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(ImmutableUpdate) });
            _ImmutableConstructors.TryAdd(type, constructor);
        }

        return constructor;
    }
```

**Four:**

Here are the builder pieces:

In `ImmutableUpdater` class:

```
public static UpdateBuilder<T> With<T, TMember>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TMember>> memberSelector, TMember newValue)
{
    ConstructorInfo immutableUpdateCtor = ImmutableUpdateConstructor(typeof(T));

    return new UpdateBuilder<T>(obj, immutableUpdateCtor).With(memberSelector, newValue);
}

public static UpdateBuilder<T> With<T, TMember>(this UpdateBuilder<T> obj, Expression<Func<T, TMember>> memberSelector, TMember newValue)
{
    if (!(memberSelector.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"You must select a member. Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
    }

    if (!(memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo selectedProperty))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"You must select a property. Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
    }

    if (selectedProperty.GetSetMethod() != null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"You must select a readonly property. Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
    }

    if (selectedProperty.Name.GetBackingField<T>() == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"You must select a pure readonly property (not a computed one). Affected expression '{memberSelector}'.");
    }

    var updates =
        from property in obj.ImmutableProperties()
        where property.Name == selectedProperty.Name
        select
            (
                property, (object)newValue
            );

    return obj.Add(updates);
}

private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ImmutableProperties<T>(this UpdateBuilder<T> obj)
{
    return
        typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() is null);
}
```

and finally, the `UpdateBuilder<T>` class:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using IEnumerablePropertyValue = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo Property, object Value)>;
using PropertyValueList = System.Collections.Generic.List<(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo Property, object Value)>;

public sealed class UpdateBuilder<T>
{
    private readonly PropertyValueList _updates = new PropertyValueList();

    private readonly ConstructorInfo _immutableUpdateCtor;

    public UpdateBuilder(T obj, ConstructorInfo immutableUpdateCtor)
    {
        this.Object = obj;
        this._immutableUpdateCtor = immutableUpdateCtor;
    }

    public T Object { get; }

    public UpdateBuilder<T> Add(IEnumerablePropertyValue updates)
    {
        foreach (var update in updates ?? Enumerable.Empty<(PropertyInfo Property, object Value)>())
        {
            this._updates.Add(update);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(UpdateBuilder<T> updateBuilder)
    {
        if (updateBuilder == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        if (updateBuilder._immutableUpdateCtor == null)
        {
            return updateBuilder.Object;
        }

        return (T)updateBuilder._immutableUpdateCtor.Invoke(new object[] { new ImmutableUpdate(updateBuilder._updates) });
    }
```

Comment: Ooops, it stayed there after _moving_ it do the helper ;-]

Comment: You must like it ;-) I see you've added a builder. I'll definitely _borrow_ it.